# iOS - Is scheduling background task with NSTimer still restricted by Apple?

Tags: ios, background, nstimer

I know I'm pulling straws, but hoping for an answer.

I have an app that needs to communicate with server in background, without user intervention. Either when push notification arrives or at least periodically (every 5 minutes or so).

I can potentially bolt-on location update and send it to server. I can even possible justify using coarse location so Apple approves it. Worst case I will pay $299 for an enterprise developer license and use local distribution (the only one I care about).

**My last hope is using periodic dispatch of a background task with NSTimer.**
Do apps using this method still fall under Apple restriction on the type of background tasks allowed? (media/location/voip/newsstand/external device) It just seems so discriminatory...

PS. The app works in development mode on ipod touch now, including periodic communication with server. I have not declared anything in plist as far as background mode. Does this mean I'm OK?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the following and got app approved by apple yesterday. My app doesn't do (media/location/voip/newsstand/external device)

You can get a max time of 600 sec(10 min) by using making use of following code in applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) { //Check if our iOS version supports multitasking I.E iOS 4
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { //Check if device supports mulitasking
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object
background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid
    //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
}];
//Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Perform your tasks that your application requires
    NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n");
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
});
}

}
```

Documentation can be found here http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

I just implemented the backgroundTaskIdentifier object and Invalidate the background_task to check the time, app was alive and was running 600sec. You can even get the remaining time by using this

```
NSLog(@"Time remaining: %f", application.backgroundTimeRemaining);
```

Comment: I think I saw similar code on the net. Someone tried the hack of dispatching another bg task close to expiration time... Not sure if that would get an app kicked out.

Comment: If the task don't end within 10min (i.e 600 sec) then app would be terminated automatically. So I wrote the code in applicationWillTerminate to handle the resume option if download is going on else if very less is downloaded, I just delete it and set it back to unavailable.

Comment: just putting this code will keep your app alive, I was doing my download on separate thread and didn't add anything in this code.

Comment: Pardon possibly stupid question, but would not your app terminate immediately after executing NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n"); - rather than waiting for 10 minutes and call expirationHandler?

Comment: I didn't add any background task , I had removed this code //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Perform your tasks that your application requires
    NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n");
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
});

Comment: background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; if this line is not used. App will be alive 10 min until watchdog finally terminate app.

Comment: I guess that's what I thought... Thank you.

Comment: I need an app to run for longer than 10 minutes, waking up briefly every 5 minutes or so. So I guess your answer does not solve this. Please correct me if I'm wrong